# ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I use Python 3.5.2 32-bit on Windows 64-bit. I get this error when I execute the project which uses Scipy, Pandas and Numpy:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  import scipy.stats as stat
 File "C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-        packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 344, in <module>
  from .stats import *
 File "C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-  packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 173, in <module>
  import scipy.special as special
File "C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\__init__.py", line 636, in <module>
 from ._ufuncs import *
File "scipy\special\_ufuncs.pyx", line 1, in init scipy.special._ufuncs    (scipy\special\_ufuncs.c:36522)
  ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

I installed these packages:

- numpy-1.11.1+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
- scipy-0.18.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl

Comment: Is there python folder in HKLM\SYSTEM\SOFTWARE and HKLM\SYSTEM\SOFTWARE\wow6432Node in regedit?

Comment: No there isn't this folder

Comment: Both of them are not there?

Comment: Which app handle `.c` files on your `OS`? Cgywin ?

Comment: It's (python, flask) .py

Comment: @ELM is your python installed in c:\Python35? If Python is installed properly, there should be registries corresponding to them in HKLM\SYSTEM\SOFTWARE\wow6432Node\Python (or) in HKLM\SYSTEM\SOFTWARE\Python

Comment: There is no software subfolder under the HKLM/SYSTEM path. That is HKLM/SOFTWARE/Python on my machine. I found nothing related to python in the HKLM/SOFTWARE/wow6432Node either.

Answer (score 0):

Open the most concerned .pyd file with [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) (the file should be somewhere in *Python35-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\special\* ) to find which dll is missing and where it is expected to be.