# Python DLL load fail after updating all packages

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I just updated all conda packages, as Jupyter had a kernel error. Had been working in Pycharm for a while, but wanted to continue in Jupyter now that the code was working. Updating fixed my jupyter kernel error, but now the script won't work, in jupyter, pycharm, or from console. I get same error in each case:

> File "myscript.py", line 58, in 
>       myFunction(path, out)   File "myscript.py", line 7, in myFunction
>       from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer, CountVectorizer   File
>   "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn__init__.py", line 134, in
>   
>       from .base import clone   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 12, in 
>       from .utils.fixes import signature   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils__init__.py", line 11, in
>   
>       from .validation import (as_float_array,   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 18,
>   in 
>       from ..utils.fixes import signature   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 144, in
>   
>       from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg__init__.py", line
>   113, in 
>       from .isolve import *   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve__init__.py",
>   line 6, in 
>       from .iterative import *   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from . import _iterative ImportError: DLL load failed

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the same Python version is used as before? Or other way around: Are you sure that the DLL's expected Python version matches the used one?

Comment: Seems like the new version is 3.6.6, I think the previous was 3.6.0

Comment: So how do I correct this?

Comment: Changes in the micro version only (like here) shouldn't lead to such problems

Answer (score 0):

Ended up unstalling anaconda and re-installing. Seems to work again now