# DLL load failure upon attempt to import sklearn modules

Tags: dll, import, scikit-learn

I'm trying to import a scikit-learn module

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

and receive the error message

```
File "C:\Software\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 45, in <module>
    from . import _arpack

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I'm not the first person to encounter this issue

([Error when trying to import sklearn modules : ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41332981/error-when-trying-to-import-sklearn-modules-importerror-dll-load-failed-the))

but neither of the remedies suggested in that discussion

1. uninstall/reinstall `scipy`
2. modify the `fixes.py` file

solved my problem. Any new ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps try re-installing several dependencies at once? `conda install numpy numpy-base scipy scikit-learn mkl --force-reinstall`

Comment: Thanks -- I gave it a try but I'm still getting the same ```DLL load failed``` error.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: I did eventually solve this problem. It took several hours, and I tried a number of things, including a full reinstallation of Anaconda, before finding that `conda uninstall scipy` followed by `pip install scipy` seemed to eliminate the issue (i.e., circumventing `conda`). I'm not totally convinced that this change alone resolved it, but may be worth trying if you're running into the same issue.